# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder.utils.iofuncs'

Tags: python, database, spyder

I want to load .spydata files with load_dictionary. However for some reason it can't find the module. I thought this was something already in Spyder? I am running spyder 3.3.1 and I don't want to update it for compatibility reasons.

```
from spyder.utils.iofuncs import load_dictionary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder.utils.iofuncs'
```

Comment: if you fire up a REPL python shell can you import the module?  have you verified that it is actually installed in in the copy of python your using to run your module?

Comment: @LhasaDad how can I do this? I don't know what REPL is, I use Anaconda Command Prompt. how do i import the module from the shell?How do I verify its installed?

Comment: i don't use anaconda, but you should be able to type python in as a command and that will start a python prompt that you can type in python statements at (REPL: Read, Execute, Print, Loop) basically what happens at the python prompt,  it reads what you type, evaluates it, prints the result and then loops to request more input.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that load_dictionary and save_dictionary was moved to the the module spyder_kernels, so

```
from spyder_kernels.utils.iofuncs import load_dictionary
```

must be used instead, see also
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-kernels/blob/master/spyder_kernels/utils/iofuncs.py .